# Residual of ARIMA model

Tags: forecasting, arima, residuals, diagnostic, acf-pacf

I've been using ARIMA recently so I'm a little bit unsettled in the chart interpretation. Currently I have 2 pictures of Ljung box and Residual in ARIMA (2,1,2). Can you help me comment on these 2 pictures? Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is your actual question about these plots ?

Comment: Yes, Sir. Because I need advice on whether these plots worked or not?

Comment: ACF: all estimated correlations is within the (blue lines) approximate confidence bands. Histogram: better show us a qq-plot, but it doesn't really look normal, but if it matters is another Q. Residuals timeseries: ? ... Maybe also show us aplot of the original timeseries, tell us what it represents, and, most importantly, what is the ultimate goal of this exercise!